# Sorting objects in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

Ok I got an array of objects in an array. Well they are actually associative arrays. So its actually an array of associative arrays.

console log outputs something like this:

```
[array object] [object{...},object{...},object{...}, etc...]
```

Each object has a name, price and color. What I want is to sort them into alphabetical order and ascending or descending in price.

I've got a jQuery code that will put them onto the page, but I need to insert a bit of code that will put them in the order I choose. Any ideas?

Comment: there's no such thing as "associative array" in javascript: that is an array of objects. You need to write your custom sort function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort (scroll about half page)

Comment: There is no such build-in method for array sorting in JS until you write an algorithm by yourself, instead you can use LINQ and do arrayObject.orderBy(x => x), try http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Comment: @VishalSachdeva: Of course there is: `Array#sort`. All you have to provide is the *comparator*, not the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the javascript array sort method that accepts a compare function as parameter.

```
var a = [{name: 'a', price: 1, color: 'red'},
{name: 'b', price: 2, color: 'red'},
{name: 'c', price: 3, color: 'blue'}];
// Ascending order
a.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.price - b.price;
});
// Descending order
a.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.price - a.price;
});
```

EDIT:
If you need to sort first by name in ascending order and then by price in ascending or descending order then:

```
// Sort by name in ascending order first and then by price in ascending order
a.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || a.price - b.price;
});
// Sort by name in ascending order first and then by price in descending order
a.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || b.price - a.price;
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Didn't see the name first sorting. Fixed.

Comment: I've never seen it done with `||` like that before, clever! I know the special way JavaScript's `||` works, I just never thought to apply it to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#sort`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) to sort arrays. It accepts a comparator callback function (a function the `sort` algorithm can use to compare two entries to see which should come first) and sorts the array in place (e.g., it doesn't make a copy of the array). The contract is: The comparator gets called with two entries, and returns `<0` if the first should come before the second, `0` if they're equal, and `>0` if the first should come after the second:

```
yourArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    // return <0 if a is less than b
    //         0 if a is equal to b
    //        >0 if a is greater than b
});
```

You can use [`String#localeCompare`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.9) to compare the names alphabetically; it conveniently returns `<0`, `0`, or `>0`. If the comparison of the names doesn't return `0`, return what it did return; if the comparison of names returns `0`, return `a.price - b.price`.